# How to add user library as dependency to play framework?

Tags: java, sbt, pubnub, playframework-2.4

I am trying to add user library to the project, but while running application showing the following errors. (may be it should be added to sbt files somehow)?
`/home/thrymr/workspace/androidBackendWorkspace/RideBackend/app/pubnub/Publisher.java:7: package com.pubnub.api does not exist
[error] com.pubnub.api.Callback
[error]`
 trying to add pubnub jars file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTDependencies. You can add additional libraries you need to `build.sbt` to the `libraryDependencies` object.